# Select from union in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, union

Is it possible to select from the result of a union? For example I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT A
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT A, B FROM TableB
)
WHERE B > 'some value'
```

Am I missing anything or making an assumption about how this works?  I'm using MSSQL 2005 so any solution will need to conform to what I can do there.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Is there any problem?

Comment: I receive the error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.' and am unable to run the query.

Comment: Missing alias name..check the answers provided

Comment: @BlargleMonster Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it worked quite well, I was just waiting out the time requirement to accept your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should give *alias* to your table. So try this:

```
SELECT A
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT A, B FROM TableB
) AS tbl
WHERE B > 'some value'
```

Answer (score 5):

Give Alias name without which you will receive

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

Try this (Give Alias Name)

```
DECLARE @TableA Table(A int, B int)
DECLARE @TableB Table(A int, B int)

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(1,2)
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(1,3)
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(1,4)

INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(2,2)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(2,3)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(2,4)

SELECT A
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B FROM @TableA
    UNION
    SELECT A, B FROM @TableB
)X -- here X is table Alias
WHERE B > 0
```

**Result**

**A**

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```